# How to debug a failing HHVM phpunit?

Tags: debugging, phpunit, hhvm

I'm trying to run our [testsuite](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/tree/master/_test) in HHVM. Unfortunately it doesn't work. PHPunit starts and then just exits without runnning a single test (exit code 255). There is no error message whatsoever and I don't know how to figure out whats wrong:

```
$> hhvm phpunit.phar 
PHPUnit 4.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/splitbrain/public_html/dw-2014-01-07/_test/phpunit.xml

$> echo $?
255
```

I tried running single test files but it seems not to matter which one I use. My guess is that something goes wrong in our bootstrapping, but I don't know how to figure out what.

Is there any way to make HHVM log a function call trace or something like that to figure out what happend last, before it exited?

Comment: Did you check HHVM's logs ? Is there anything relevant there about this ?

Comment: there are no logs to be found. (this is running from commandline)